# How could I play two sounds together?

Tags: java, audio

Well, I am writing a gaming project using java and I want to implement something like this : when an object begins to move, it makes some sound effects, and when another object begins to move before the first object stops, it also makes some sound effects. After the second object begins to move and before the first object stops moving, how can I merge the sounds of two objects instead of playing them seperately?

Answer (score 0):

Most of this will be achieved using the [`java.sound.sampled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) library. Focus on [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html)'s functionality. [This site](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html) provides some really good boilerplate using both samples and MIDI files. It even has an example for gaming.

Anyway, based off of StackOverflow's [javasound page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info), here is a crude example of playing two `Clip`s at once:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    URL url1 = new URL("http://www.websitewithsomewav/noise1.wav");
    Clip clip1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream stream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url1);
    clip1.open(stream1);

    URL url2 = new URL("http://www.websitewithsomewav/noise2.wav");
    Clip clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream stream2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url2);
    clip2.open(ais2);

    clip1.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    clip2.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
            // from terminating at the end of the main()
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
        }
    });
}
```

### Update

If you absolutely *must* use a single input stream, you can try [`MixingAudioInputStream`](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/MixingAudioInputStream.java.html)

Comment: Thank you though what I expect is:

Comment: 1. clip1 starts before clip2

Comment: 2. When clip2 starts, it mergers with clip1. And we play something new like clip3 which is a combination of clip1 and clip2

Comment: I'm not sure why this is necessary -- it sounds like a potential [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- but I've updated the answer with an API that lets you merge streams. I've not tried it myself but it may be what you're looking for.